# TimePickerDialog in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, timepickerdialog

I have this code from the [material3](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#DatePicker(androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerState,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerFormatter,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.DatePickerColors)) documentation for compose:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHost
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TimeInput
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberTimePickerState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope

var showTimePicker by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val state = rememberTimePickerState()
val formatter = remember { SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()) }
val snackState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val snackScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Box(propagateMinConstraints = false) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
        onClick = { showTimePicker = true }
    ) { Text("Set Time") }
    SnackbarHost(hostState = snackState)
}

if (showTimePicker) {
    TimePickerDialog(
        onCancel = { showTimePicker = false },
        onConfirm = {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, state.hour)
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, state.minute)
        cal.isLenient = false
        snackScope.launch {
            snackState.showSnackbar("Entered time: ${formatter.format(cal.time)}")
        }
        showTimePicker = false
    },
) {
    TimeInput(state = state)
}
}
```

Pretty straightforward right?
But android studio is complaining about `TimePickerDialog` with:

```
<html>None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:<br/>public constructor TimePickerDialog(context: Context!, listener: TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener!, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int, is24HourView: Boolean) defined in android.app.TimePickerDialog<br/>public constructor TimePickerDialog(context: Context!, themeResId: Int, listener: TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener!, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int, is24HourView: Boolean) defined in android.app.TimePickerDialog
```

With a bit of googling of found most of the example code regarding TimePickerDialog or DatePickerDialog weren't using the Picker dialogs as explained in the documentation above.

```
val mTimePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
    mContext,
    {_, mHour : Int, mMinute: Int ->
        mTime.value = "$mHour:$mMinute"
    }, mHour, mMinute, false
)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `TimePickerDialog` is not included in the M3 package (`1.1.0-beta01`).
You can use:

```
@Composable
fun TimePickerDialog(
    title: String = "Select Time",
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: () -> Unit,
    toggle: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onCancel,
        properties = DialogProperties(
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
        ),
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
            tonalElevation = 6.dp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .background(
                    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                ),
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                    text = title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium
                )
                content()
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(40.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    toggle()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = onCancel
                    ) { Text("Cancel") }
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = onConfirm
                    ) { Text("OK") }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[Source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/samples/material3/samples/TimePickerSamples.kt;l=230;drc=03ca30d22e6ee3483142f2e4048db459cb5afb79)

Comment: Ah classic from Google! Documentation that only works in the future.

Comment: Looks like it's still not included in 1.2.0-alpha03 of compose-material3 :/

Comment: I had created an issue and the official recommendation is to copy the code. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288311426

Answer (score 0):

Gabriele answer is fine for the classic TimePicker, if you need both modes Input and Picker, this is the full code adapted from his source code link.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TimePickerDialog(
    onCancel: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: (Calendar) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val time = Calendar.getInstance()
    time.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

    var mode: DisplayMode by remember { mutableStateOf(DisplayMode.Picker) }
    val timeState: TimePickerState = rememberTimePickerState(
        initialHour = time[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY],
        initialMinute = time[Calendar.MINUTE],
    )

    fun onConfirmClicked() {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timeState.hour)
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timeState.minute)
        cal.isLenient = false

        onConfirm(cal)
    }

    // TimePicker does not provide a default TimePickerDialog, so we use our own PickerDialog:
    // https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/288311426
    PickerDialog(
        modifier = modifier,
        onDismissRequest = onCancel,
        title = { Text("Select hour") },
        buttons = {
            DisplayModeToggleButton(
                displayMode = mode,
                onDisplayModeChange = { mode = it },
            )
            Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
            TextButton(onClick = onCancel) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
            TextButton(onClick = ::onConfirmClicked) {
                Text("Confirm")
            }
        },
    ) {
        val contentModifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
        when (mode) {
            DisplayMode.Picker -> TimePicker(modifier = contentModifier, state = timeState)
            DisplayMode.Input -> TimeInput(modifier = contentModifier, state = timeState)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun DisplayModeToggleButton(
    displayMode: DisplayMode,
    onDisplayModeChange: (DisplayMode) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    when (displayMode) {
        DisplayMode.Picker -> IconButton(
            modifier = modifier,
            onClick = { onDisplayModeChange(DisplayMode.Input) },
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_keyboard),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }

        DisplayMode.Input -> IconButton(
            modifier = modifier,
            onClick = { onDisplayModeChange(DisplayMode.Picker) },
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_schedule),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun PickerDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    buttons: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    AlertDialog(
        modifier = modifier
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
            tonalElevation = 6.dp,
        ) {
            Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                // Title
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant) {
                    ProvideTextStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.Start)
                                .padding(horizontal = 24.dp)
                                .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 20.dp),
                        ) {
                            title()
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Content
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides AlertDialogDefaults.textContentColor) {
                    content()
                }
                // Buttons
                CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentColor provides MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary) {
                    ProvideTextStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge) {
                        // TODO This should wrap on small screens, but we can't use AlertDialogFlowRow as it is no public
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(bottom = 8.dp, end = 6.dp, start = 6.dp),
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp, Alignment.End),
                        ) {
                            buttons()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[[image]]